# using UINavigationBar without UINavigationController

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationbar

I want a UINavigationBar at the top of my UIWebView but I want to control by hand the title, the back button, what the back button does - etc. In other words I never want to push or pop views. I just want to change the UINavigationBar contents as the user clicks around the web view.

Where I'm up to is I added the UINavigationBar to my superView and made it 44 pixels tall. How do I set the title since I have no navigationItem? How would I set a fake back button up?

I would appreciate any pointers. I realise this is quite weird what I'm doing.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The answer, if anyone's interested, is in the class reference of UINavigationBar.

> When you use a navigation bar as a standalone object, you are
>   responsible for providing its contents. **Unlike other types of views**,
>   you do not add subviews to a navigation bar directly. Instead, you use
>   **a navigation item** (an instance of the UINavigationItem class) to
>   specify what buttons or custom views you want displayed. A navigation
>   item has properties for specifying views on the left, right, and
>   center of the navigation bar and for specifying a custom prompt
>   string.

In short, use a UINavigationItem and apply it by "pushNavigationItem" on the UINavigationBar.

I created a subclass of UINavigationBar called StaticNavigationBar which I can then load with any state by putting the appropriate UINavigationItem's on it. Thanks for all your answers people.

Comment: Why did you have to subclass?

Comment: You don't really @David - in fact these days I prefer composition over inheritance.

Comment: Apparently using `navigationBar.setItems(items, animated: true)` causes some kind of bug where the status bar color disappears, even if the original value of the `navigationBar.items` is `nil`. +1 for the answer.

Answer (score -1):

You can have that UINavigationBar as an outlet and then you can manupulate it as you want. So you don't have to refer to somebody's navigation item. It'll be an independent (sort of) object on your view.

Comment: I have my UINavigationBar on the view. Now what do I call to set the title? Add a back button?

Comment: UINavigationBar has a backItem property. When it comes to title you'll have to do it via navigation item property which can also be added in IB or Storyboard as an outlet. The navigation item has title property.

Answer (score -1):

If you dont want the navigationbar as-is youll have to roll your own.
if youre ok with the built in animations for pushing and popping items(dont confuse with push/pop of viewcontrollers) to the bar you would then set your UINavigationBarDelegate and use its methods for controlling how things push/pop, etc.

Comment: I like the UINavigationBar how it looks natively. I want to know how to set the title and back button programmatically in the absence of a uinavigationcontroller. So far I've only been able to add it to the view and set the tint. Can't see methods to set the title or add back buttons.