# Adding a bar button Item to Navigation bar in view storyboard

Tags: ios, iphone

This might be a silly question but I am trying to add a bar button item on a view without the need of a navigation controller in the Storyboard. For some reason when I set the navigation bar visible and try to drag the bar button item it does not stick any suggestions? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9188793/using-uinavigationbar-without-uinavigationcontroller

Comment: When you say "...when I set the navigation bar visible..." you mean you set the Top Bar attribute to Opaque Navigation Bar or similar?

Comment: I was adding the simulated metrics, top bar from inferred to navigation bar

Answer (score 1):

You are probably setting the **Simulated Metrics** Top Bar as a Navigation Bar, but that, as the name says, only SIMULATES those objects, and don't insert them on your view. That is why you can't insert the Bar Button in something that is not there.

EDIT

You could try [self.navigationController.navigationBar setHidden:YES] to hide the "second bar" that might appear after inserting the true nav bar.

Hope it helps...

Comment: Thank you, I did see that but when I add a navigation bar myself with a button, it work but I see two bars instead

Comment: You could try [self.navigationController.navigationBar setHidden:YES] to hide the "second bar"...

Comment: do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Sure! No problem! Just mark the answer as the correct one, I've edited with the comment.